# Docker : External DNS resolution when using user-defined network

Tags: docker, docker-network

When I used the default bridge network generated by Docker daemon, I run this command:

`docker run -it --dns=10.xxx.xxx.xxx  961bf2f8b1b2`

The external DNS resolution works well without any problem, but when I use an user-defined network created like this:

`docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 dockernet`

and then I run :
`docker run -it --dns=10.xxx.xxx.xxx --network dockernet 961bf2f8b1b2`

DNS resolution doesn't work anymore.

I use a workaround to fix that by bind my /etc/resolv.conf like this:

`docker run -it --dns=10.xxx.xxx.xxx --network dockernet -v /etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf 961bf2f8b1b2`

I guess there is a more suitable solution.

Comment: This workaround is pretty bad because the embedded dns server doesn't work with this solution.

Comment: Did u try to ping dns server inside your container?

Comment: Yes I can ping DNS server from my container.

Comment: Have you tried stopping firewall on host? I just simulated your scenario, it works well in both way.

Comment: Nop, I'll try, I'll let you know

Comment: It's probably not a firewall issue because my container can communicate with the rest of world without any problem. It's just that my container don't use my external dns provider to resolv machine name...